# TypeError: AWS.Batch is not a constructor

Tags: aws-sdk-js, aws-batch

using

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.127.0.min.js"></script>
```

this is supposed to work:

```
var batch = new AWS.Batch();
VM81:1 Uncaught TypeError: AWS.Batch is not a constructor
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

what gives?

Comment: ok apparently Batch does not allow CORS, so perhaps that's why it's not exposed here...
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/SERVICES.md